# CSS contains commas and it doesn't work on IOS. How can I fix this?

Tags: css

This css is not working on IOS.
What I found is that comma in the --color is not working on IOS.So the progress bar's color is not apearing appropriately.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
[codepen][1]

```css
progress[value] {
  --w: 10em; /* the width*/
  --color:  /* the progress color */
    /* if < 30% "red" */
    linear-gradient(red    0 0) 0 /calc(var(--w)*.3 - 100%) 1px,
    /* if < 60% "orange" */
    linear-gradient(orange 0 0) 0 /calc(var(--w)*.6 - 100%) 1px,
    /* else "green" */
    green;
  --background: lightgrey; /* the background color */

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  width: var(--w);
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: var(--background);
  -webkit-mask:
   radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#000 98%,#0000 102%) 0/12.5% 100%,
   linear-gradient(90deg,#000 50%, #0000 0) 8%/25% 100%
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: var(--background);
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: var(--color);
}
progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: var(--color);
}

label {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<label> label: <progress max="100" value="10">10%</progress></label>
<label> label: <progress max="100" value="40">40%</progress></label>
<label> label: <progress max="100" value="80">80%</progress></label>
<label> label: <progress max="100" value="100">100%</progress></label>
```

Comment: progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar   &  progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar colors are same?

Comment: What browser you use in iOS? Does it persist on different browsers too?

Comment: @JaswinderKaur — why would you want to specify different values for the same property (just different experimental implementations of it in different browsers)?

Comment: Please note that `calc` will not work in Safari 9.1 till 9.3: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=161002

Comment: @Justinas — Does that really matter? Apple’s rules forbid any iOS browser not being a wrapper around the mobile safari rendering engine.

Comment: @justinas all browsers in IOS has same problem.

Comment: @jaswinderkaur This is for a progress bar that shows different colors of progress based on the value.

Comment: I made that code and it won't work on Safari because of the complex logic used inside background. I don't know why (and I don't really want to know) but it's clearly a bug as it should work fine

Comment: @temaniafif Nice to know who made it, it was exactly what I needed. comma in --color doesn't seem to apply multiple styles.